# How to find vertices of square in complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Given a square with vertices: $\sqrt3+i,-1+i\sqrt3,-i-\sqrt3,1-i\sqrt3$

So that  a circle that is centered in the origin is blocking the square.

My question is how can I find the vertices of a square (different one) that blocks this  origin centerd circle such that his sides are parallel to the first square I mentioned.

Is there any easy way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Find modulus of those complex numbers

Comment: By "blocks the circle" I'm guessing you mean "tangent to the circle". Am I right?

Comment: @Timbuc - yes that's what i meant

Comment: If i multiply the vertices by $\sqrt2$ it will work but it's just guessing.

Comment: @ari, that will not work: the new square's sides *cannot* be on the same sides of the original square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started with a square $Q$, centered at the origin, whose diagonals have length $d$. The circle $C$ circumscribing this square has diameter $d$. You want to find the square $Q'$ circumscribing $C$ whose sides are parallel to the sides of $Q$.

Since $Q$ is centered at the origin, $Q'$ is just a rescaling of $Q$. In other words, there is some positive real number $\lambda$ with the property that $Q' = \{\lambda z : z \in Q\}$. For short, I'll just write $Q' = \lambda Q$.

To get $Q'$, all we have to do is find $\lambda$. To find $\lambda$, notice that the sides of $Q'$ must have length $d$. On the other hand, the sides of $Q$ have length $\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}$, so the sides of $Q'$ will have length $\lambda \frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}$. That means you should pick $\lambda = \sqrt{2}$, just like you guessed.

***@Semiclassical*** drew a nice picture of $Q$, $C$, and $Q'$. Looking at the right triangles formed by the extra lines they drew from the center, you can see quite directly that the diagonals of $Q$, the diameter of $C$, and the sides of $Q'$ are the same length.

[image]

Comment: The following [diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IJW6T.png) may be useful. Feel free to steal it if you like, though you may have to resize it.

Comment: so as i said, you can also get it by $r=Rcos\frac{\pi}{4}$ so that $R=2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical, that's beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: This answer deserves upvotes. +1

Comment: @Timbuc, I'm glad you like it!

Comment: @ari, yup! It's clear from Semiclassical's picture that the half-diagonal of $Q'$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle whose side is the radius of $C$, which in turn is the half-diagonal of $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

The given square is circumscribed by the circle $\;|z|=2\;$ (why?), and we want a new square circumscribing this circle, and from here that each of its sides will be of length $\;2\cdot2=4=\;$ the circle's diameter.

Both squares will be concentric, meaning the four diagonals of them will meet in one single point and with sides parallel.

An idea for finding the vertices of the new suqare (disclaimer: it is not claimed this is the only or even the fastest/simplest way to do it).

For example, take the middle point of the first square's "right" side $\;\ell:=[(1,-\sqrt3)\;,\;(\sqrt3,1)]\;$  is

$$M_r=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt3}2\;,\;\;\frac{1-\sqrt3}2\right)$$

the line through the above point and the origin is

$$y=\frac{1-\sqrt3}{1+\sqrt3}x=(\sqrt3-2)x$$

and the middle point of the new side parallel to $\;\ell\;$ will be on this line (why?) and at length $\;2\;$ from the origin, so we need a point

$$\left(x\;,\;(\sqrt3-2)x\right)\;\;s.t.\;\; x^2+(5-4\sqrt3)x^2=4$$

Solve this and you have your new square's right side's middle point, and then you can calculate the line on which this new side is on (you've the point **and** the line's slope. Why?), adn you need both vertices to be at a distance of $\;2\;$ from this new middle point...and etc.

Please note the above is basic (analytic and plain) geometry.

Comment: that's long but constructive. my guess was to multiply the vertices by $\sqrt2$ because: $r=Rcos\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @ari, that will certainly give you points on the circumscribing circle but those **cannot** be the vertices of the wanted new square. Do a little drawing to understand this: it's impossilbe the new square *circumscribing the circle* has its sides on the same lines the old square's sides were.

Comment: yes i just drew and understood now. so do you think any use of the complex numbers will shorten the solution here?

Comment: Well @ari, my ideas for a solution above use the fact the complex numbers are isomorphic (i.e., "the same") as the real plane $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ , and allows us to work with analytic geometry, say.

Comment: @Timbuc, how can multiplying the vertices by $\sqrt{2}$ yield points on the circle circumscribing the original square? The vertices themselves were on the circle circumscribing the original square, so their multiples cannot be!

Comment: @Vectornaut -i didn't say the new vertices will be on that circle. ofcourse they won't be. if you mulitplying by $\sqrt2$ the old vertices it's just moving them outside the circle.

Comment: @ari, I agree with you. That's why I'm confused! Timbuc wrote, "[multiplying by $\sqrt{2}$] will certainly give you points on the circumscribing circle," which seems wrong to me. I commented to ask Timbuc for clarification.

Comment: @Vectornaut - sorry i didn't see you wrote to him:)

Comment: @Vectornaut, you are right: that was a mistake. I was trying to say those points would be in the bigger, new *square*, but even this isn't sure. Erase that. I just confused between square circumscribing circle and the other way around. Never mind, it wouldn't work either way.

Comment: Timbuc: in that case, do you think @ari's guess about scaling by $\sqrt{2}$ might actually be correct? The argument in my answer seems to indicate that scaling by $\sqrt{2}$ is the right thing to do, and I can't find a mistake in it. Are you certain that the procedure you described gives a different result than scaling by $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Vectornaut, sorry for not answering before. Somehow this message slip under my radar. Yes, I think that re-scaling may be helpful, as I was obviously mistaken when I ruled out thi idea.